# Model and Seeding Difference in Laravel

Tags: model, laravel-5.1, laravel-seeding

I am confused what's the difference of **seeding** and by using **model** in laravel which both saving data into the database. Why not just use **Model**?  or Why not **Seed**? When and why they used?

Answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeds are used to put static or test to database for *once*. Everytime you run seeders your data tables will be truncated and seeded again.

However Models are dynamic they can recieve data from controller directly from forms, API's or files etc.

P.S: You can use files, API's for seeding too but evertime you put new file to same table old one will be truncated

Comment: Ow, seeds are just for testing?

Comment: not only for testing but for static data that will not be changed. For example test user or country list, or as you say test data

Comment: That's great, thank you for your answer, and also the one who voted down my question.